# Indirect Speech: they said that that change.... is correct?

Tags: indirect-speech

I want to transform this sentence

> "This change is good" - Teachers

to indirect speech:

> The teachers said that that change was good.

Is this sentences correct? Can I use double that?

Comment: "use double that"?

Comment: 'The teachers said that that change was good.' or 'The teachers said that this change was good.' are both possible. The 'that' after 'said' is the complementiser, unlike the 'that' (or 'this') before 'change'.

Comment: Proofreading or writing advice requests are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Mostly OK.... But "that change was good", singular.  Are you trying for subjunctive or something?

Answer (score 0):

As "good" points to "change" (singular), you would use "was good" or "is good" instead of "were good". Since the original quote uses "is", it would be best to carry that over to ensure accuracy.

Otherwise, it would be correct. The word "that" can be used twice in this situation.